# Is it possible to disable reading hosts file by libCurl

Tags: c++, libcurl

There is a detection in VirusTotal: `remote System Discovery T1018: Reads the hosts file`. For testing I want to get rid of this detection. I suppose that it is libCurl, who reading this file.
Is it possible to disable libCurl from reading `hosts` and what are consequenses of that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` option to explicitly specify the IP address of the remote host in the request. This will bypass the need for libCurl to resolve the hostname using the hosts file.

Comment: Thanks. But if I will use `CURLOPT_RESOLVE ` and remote host name and not an IP, will cUrl use DNS and ignore `hosts` or I really need to use IP?

Comment: I tried to set empty `curl_slist` to `CURLOPT_RESOLVE` option, but VirusTotal still shows detect. For internet work I use only cUrl, so I think this option doesn't work fo my problem